# Loop through all the DBSet(of TEntity) on a DBContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using entity Framework 6.1, DbContext, Database First.
I know that I can get the DBsets by names like: context.Myobj1 , context.Myobj2.....

But Is there any possibility to do a for...each loop and to get one by one all the DbSet(of Tentity) on a DbContext?

Comment: You can use reflection. This is what DbContext does to discover the model.

Comment: Have a look at http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/
Something like `(((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace).GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace).Single().EntitySets` should do the trick

Answer (score -3):

You need to discover types of entities. That depends on your application. You can use reflection to discover those types. Or you can hardcode types of your entities.

After this you can loop though sets:

```
var types = new [] { typeof(User), typeof(Role) }; // just example

foreach(var type in types)
{
    foreach(var entity in context.DbSet(type))
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: *"You can use reflection to discover those types"* - yeah, the question was how to do this. *"Or you can hardcode types of your entities"* - well, sure, but that's not very helpful.